# AngularJS Read From JSON Returning Nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-get

I am building an application that has a button that loads up help based on IDs from the JSON, when I have the JSON in the controller.js I see it on the web page but if I do it externally I do not see anything. I feel I am missing something extremely simple but may be over looking it. Any ideas?

controllerNEW.js

```
app.factory("UserService", function($rootScope, $http){
     function getFile(){
       return $http.get('stat.json').then(function(data) {
            return data;
        }); 
    } 

    return{statErr: getFile,

        //hide the displayed tooltip based on its id
        hideTooltip: function(key, scopes, data)
        {
```

controllerOLD.js

```
app.factory("UserService", function($rootScope){
    return{
        statErr: [
            {
                selector: "#userEmail",
                fieldTitle: "Email",
                placement: "right",
                content: "test",
                offsetTop: 500,
                correctKey: "@test",
                inErrorList: false
            },
            {
                selector: "#userId",
                fieldId: "id1",
                fieldTitle: "ID",
                placement: "right",
                content: " number should contain 4 zeroes '...0000...'",
                offsetTop: 500,
                correctKey: "0000",
                inErrorList: false
            }
        ],

        //hide the displayed tooltip based on its id
        hideTooltip: function(key, scopes, data)
        {
```

Comment: To see the response of your data, the callback is `data.data`

Comment: `function(data) { return data; }` is just returning data... into oblivion. You're not treating it and not doing anything with it.

Comment: I am calling the function which I expected would return the data

Comment: Another change could just leave the request in your service and execute the promise in your controller. In fact, that is the good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `getFile()` returns a promise not the data itself. It is true that you have a `.then(function(data) {return data; });`, but, **`.then()` also returns a promise.**

So to fix this issue, in your actual code, after you call `getFile()` you also need to add `.then()` to have access to your data:

```
getFile().then(function(data){
 // now you have access to your data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the **data** object in the response object.

example:

```
var jsonResponse = $http.get('content.json').then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
```

Comment: when you "console.log" the response, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `data` is the whole response to your request, including headers and status. To see your data from the `'stat.json'` file, you would access the `data` object of your `data`. So, the change is.

```
function getFile(){
       return $http.get('stat.json').then(function(data) {
            return data.data;
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: please, show me the controller where you are calling the `service`. I don't see where is the implementation

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
 $http.get('stat.json').then(function(result){
     $scope.dataset = result.data
     console.log($scope.dataset)
    },function(error){
     console.log(error)
    })
```